# Convert Pages '13 files to PDF in batch

Tags: terminal, pdf, batch, conversion

I have tons of Pages files lying around taking up precious space on my SSD.

I want to batch convert them to PDF preferably via a terminal command. I have iWork '13 and iWork '09. AppleScript-ability of Pages has historically been bad. Who has ideas?

Comment: Those pages are in what format? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Check out [this script](https://discussions.apple.com/message/8794866#8794866) by Yvan Koenig

Comment: Pages '13 aka the new iWork version that was released with Mavericks. I don't understand why this question gets downvoted.

I have tried old Applescripts by googling but they no longer work (and didn't work with Pages '09 either).

Comment: Can you upload them to google drive and have google print as pdf, batch style?

Answer (score 0):

> Well... you need something that
>
> 1. understand the iWork file formats,
> 2. can render the documents to then create the PDF.
>
> Unless you want to re-invent the iWork suite...  Sounds simpler to
>   just tell the iWork apps what you want from them.
>
> You would do that via the [Scripting
>   Bridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html)
>
> I would use Applescript, but perhaps you can use [Ruby and
>   Python](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/RubyPythonCocoa/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004936)
>   with the Scripting Bridge [to accomplish what you
>   need](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/RubyPythonCocoa/Articles/UsingScriptingBridge.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005424-SW1)
>
> > With Scripting Bridge, RubyCocoa and PyObjC scripts can do what AppleScript scripts can do: control scriptable applications and
> >     exchange data with them.
>
> I haven't used the Scripting Bridge in a while, but I believe you can
>   tell applications to print documents.  And any application that can
>   print in OS X can send it to PDF instead.

Answer was found here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014807/batch-convert-mac-iwork-files-to-pdf-on-the-command-line.